# DatePickerIOS in react-native and user locale

Tags: react-native, datepicker

We've implemented DatePickerIOS from react-native but it doesn't seem to respect the device locale for dates.

I'm in Norway right now, and it is correctly showing a 24 hour picker without AM/PM, but the text still says "Today", "Thu 5 Oct", "Fri 6 Oct". It should be more like "I dag", "Tor 5 Okt", "Fre 6 Okt"

RN version 0.47.1

[image]

Comment: Whats your device's language? (not locale)

Answer (score 2):

open 'Info.plist' file in 'ios' folder using Xcode or other text editors, change 'CFBundleDevelopmentRegion' to your locale's name, then retry

Comment: Mine is 'fr_FR' and still the month shows in english.